# AssertionError for tfrecord_dir in stylegan . What should be correct argument?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I try to run stylegan training.py it throws AssertionError as follows. What should be the correct `tfrecord_dir` argument ?

In training.py it has ;

```
desc += '-dataset';     
dataset = EasyDict(tfrecord_dir='dataset', resolution=128); 
train.mirror_augment = False
```

I put `tfrecord_dir` argument as `dataset`. The path should be correct. My tfrecords path is `\stylegan\dataset`. My `training.py` path is `\stylegan`.

This is my error:

```
PS C:\Users\dell> & C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/dell/Desktop/Data Science/GAN/stylegan/train.py"

File "c:\Users\dell\Desktop\Data Science\GAN\stylegan\training\dataset.py", line 71, in __init__
    assert os.path.isdir(self.tfrecord_dir)
AssertionError
```

Paths are as follows:

tfrecords_path:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlYi7.png]

training.py & tfrecords_path:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltumK.png]

Comment: Where are this files coming from ? Can you please add a link?

Comment: hi @ClaudiaR I uploaded all files to google drive.Dataset is in dataset folder 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Rc81XOyPYs4fOhQyTytFqGj4zaCb9VC?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You have to set `self.tfrecord_dir= '../dataset/'`

**Long answer:**

I had a look at the files. Ok so basically the error comes from the line:

```
assert os.path.isdir(self.tfrecord_dir)
```

It means that the path you have inserted in `self.tfrecord_dir` is not recognized as a directory.

You set: `self.tfrecord_dir= '\stylegan\dataset'`

This is your file structure:

```
/stylegan/dataset/ 
/stylegan/training/dataset.py
```

You are executing the code from inside the `training` directory, and you want to go two position up from that, in `stylegan`, to be able to access `dataset`.

Adding `./` before your path lets you access the files of the parent directory of your current position. If you add `../` you get what you need. This leaves us with:

```
self.tfrecord_dir= '../dataset/'
```

Comment: I posted the correct answer. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.You have to set `self.tfrecord_dir= 'mars'` and the dataset should be under `./datasets/mars` folder.